# Is there a way to create a Drag and Drop input for file upload in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I need to change my simple upload-input field into a 'drag and drop' upload.

I did some research but haven't found any clue on Angular 5. I tried using ngx-file-drop but I've got compatibility errors.

```
@angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-file-drop@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-file-drop@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-file-drop@6.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-file-drop@6.0.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I would like to see examples and implementations for drag and drop in an Angular 5 project.

Comment: These dependency warnings are just what they are, warnings. If you get no errors, you can just safely use this. Or install an older version of ngx-file-drop, which does support angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular-file-uploader` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader). Angular file uploader is an Angular 2/4/5/6 file uploader module with Real-Time Progress Bar, Angular Universal Compatibility and multiple themes which includes Drag and Drop and much more.

Or you can use [ng-file-upload](https://hackernoon.com/implementing-ng-file-upload-in-angular-2-app-397bae30ae99) for drag and drop file upload.